# How to retrieve image from Django through database?

Tags: python, django, database, django-models, authentication

I am trying to have user see their photo once they login. The images already saved into the db, I just need it to appear once they login.

Here is my Models & Forms:

Models:
I am trying to have user see their photo once they login. The images already saved into the db, I just need it to appear once they login.

Here is my Models & Forms:

Models:
class UserProfileInfo(models.Model):

```
class UserProfileInfo(models.Model):

    # Create relationship (don't inherit from User!)
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)

    # Add any additional attributes you want
    portfolio_site = models.URLField(blank=True)
    # pip install pillow to use this!
    profile_pic = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_pics',blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        # Built-in attribute of django.contrib.auth.models.User !
        return self.user.username
```

Forms:

```
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())

    class Meta():
        model = User
        fields = ('username','email','password')

class UserProfileInfoForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta():
        model = UserProfileInfo
        fields = ('portfolio_site','profile_pic')
```

in Views.py:

```
def register(request):
    registered = False
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # Get info from "both" forms
        # It appears as one form to the user on the .html page
        user_form = UserForm(data=request.POST)
        profile_form = UserProfileInfoForm(data=request.POST)

        # Check to see both forms are valid
        if user_form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():
            # Save User Form to Database
            user = user_form.save()
            # Hash the password
            user.set_password(user.password)
            # Update with Hashed password
            user.save()
            # Now we deal with the extra info!
            # Can't commit yet because we still need to manipulate
            profile = profile_form.save(commit=False)
            # Set One to One relationship between
            # UserForm and UserProfileInfoForm
            profile.user = user
            # Check if they provided a profile picture
            if 'profile_pic' in request.FILES:
                print('found it')
                # If yes, then grab it from the POST form reply
                profile.profile_pic = request.FILES['profile_pic']
            # Now save model
            profile.save()
            # Registration Successful!
            registered = True
        else:
            # One of the forms was invalid if this else gets called.
            print(user_form.errors,profile_form.errors)
    else:
        # Was not an HTTP post so we just render the forms as blank.
        user_form = UserForm()
        profile_form = UserProfileInfoForm()
    # This is the render and context dictionary to feed
    # back to the registration.html file page.
    return render(request,'basic_app/registration.html',
                          {'user_form':user_form,
                           'profile_form':profile_form,
                           'registered':registered})
```

Comment: please, show code of your views.py and html template

Comment: Please refer to edited version!

Answer (score 0):

i think you need replace:

```
profile_form = UserProfileInfoForm(data=request.POST)
```

to

```
profile_form = UserProfileInfoForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
```

more details [django file-uploads](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/file-uploads/)